# Display multiple input values each in a new line in one div Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a form where a user can input many descriptions and later view all the details that he\she has inputed. I am using a repeating region to gather this descriptions(in a texfield with id description) and I want the user to be able to preview the info they have provided before printing/saving

Is there a way I can collect all the information in the repeated textfield id(description) and display them in one div as they appear? e.g if a user types in the first row - "Stack" and in the second repeated row "Overflow"./ The user should see:

- Stack
- Overflow

(Ignore the bullets) in a particular divtag. Basically I need to fetch all input with Id description and display each of them in a new line in a div.

All help greatly appreciated

**EDIT:
Here is the HTML code**

```
 <tr>
    <td><label for="description"></label>
      <textarea name="description" cols="35" rows="2" id="description"></textarea></td>
    <td><label for="accountcodes"></label>
      <input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase;" name="accountcodes" id="accountcodes"></td>
    <td width="10" align="center">T1
      <label for="T1"></label>
      <input name="T1" type="text" class="tcodes" id="T1" size="10"></td>
    <td width="10" align="center">T2
      <label for="T2"></label>
      <input name="T2" type="text" class="tcodes" id="T2" size="10"></td>
    <td width="20" align="center">T3
      <label for="T3"></label>
      <input name="T3" type="text" class="tcodes" id="T3" size="15"></td>
    <td width="10" align="center">T4
      <label for="T4"></label>
      <input name="T4" type="text" class="tcodes" id="T4" size="10"></td>
    <td width="10" align="center">T5
      <label for="T5"></label>
      <input name="T5" type="text" class="tcodes" id="T5" size="10"></td>
    <td width="10" align="center">T6
      <label for="T6"></label>
      <input name="T6" type="text" class="tcodes" id="T6" size="10"></td>
    <td width="10" align="center">T8
      <label for="T8"></label>
      <input name="T8" type="text" class="tcodes" id="T8" size="10"></td>
    <td><label for="amount"></label>
      <input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" size="10"></td>
    <td><a id="deletedesc" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000;" href="#delete">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Just need all inputs with ID description to be displayed in one div each in a new line. The above is the HTML code I am cloning

**NEW EDIT**

Using some piece of code from Ninja, I have come up with this jquery code but I must use an alert for it to work and it works for Firefox only

```
$("#preview").click(function(){
    var description = '';
    var accountcodes='';
    $("#loadpage").show();
    $("#loadpage").load("pvpreview.php");
    //append all descriptions   
    $("#descriptiontable #description").each(function() 
    {
     description = $(this).val(); 
     //alert(description)
     $("#prevdescription").append('<p>' + description + '</p>');
}); 
    //append all account codes
    $("#descriptiontable #accountcodes").each(function() 
    { 
     accountcodes = $(this).val();  
     $("#prevaccountcodes").appendTo('<p>' + accountcodes + '</p>');
}); 


    });
```

Please note I am appending to a page that is being loaded. #prevdescription and #prevacountcodes are in the loaded page

Comment: Some html would help. Also, try to avoid making more than one element with the same id

Comment: Please provide the htmt for the rows

Comment: @ori it's the same ID because I am cloning the table rows

Comment: Should I use a .find function and a .each function then display them in a div?

Answer (score 2):

Ít's incorrect to give multiple input elements with same id. Use class instead. Assuming your input elements are:

```
<input class="myClass" type="text" id="1">
<input class="myClass" type="text" id="2"> 
<div id="output"></div>
```

You can use jquery .each():

```
$(".myClass").each(function() {
    description = $(this).val();
    $("#output").append('<p>' + description + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: I must use an alert so that I can see the results and I cant tell why

Comment: They appear and immediately disappear

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple elements with the same id is invalid HTML, and you don't get all the elements when you select by id: `$('#ID')`. You'll only get the first one.

You can either give the input element a class and then query `$('.CLASS')`, or use the input's name attribute `$('input[name="NAME"]')`.

The [loop over the elements](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and append the value to your container --don't forget to empty the container first.